# How do I convert JavaScript confirm to HTML5 button actions?

Tags: javascript, button, input, submit, confirm

I have the following code:

```
if(changedStatus()){
    var mAns = confirm("You have changed your status. This will alter your estate plan and may cause you to lose some data. Are you sure that you want to do this?");
    if(!mAns) return false; 
}
```

This works great with the default JS confirm pop-up, but I would like to implement the same action with HTML5 buttons instead:

```
<div id="cres_statusmssg">
  <p>Changing your status will alter your estate plan and may cause you to lose some data. Do you want to proceed?</p>
   <button id="cres_yes">Yes</button>
   <button id="cres_cancel">Cancel</button>
```

I have applied click events to both buttons, but I can't get them to work. Any ideas?

Comment: _"but I can't get them to work"_ - you haven't showed this

Comment: share your complete code

Comment: Are you sure that you can use `return` in `if`?

Comment: Do you understand asynchrony? You'll need to.  Anyway. Buttons don't just do things as if by majicks they know what you expect them to do. You'll need to act on the click event they dispatch

Comment: @NNL993 why would you question the part of the code that works?

Comment: P.s. buttons aren't a HTML 5 thing.  I think they've been around since html 1

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to understand how to write for asynchrony, since there is no other way to achieve what you want to do. The built-in `confirm` (and `prompt`, `alert` etc) effectively pause JS execution until the user has interacted with the pop-up

Writing nicer pop-ups, you don't have that luxury. You'll need to use *callbacks* to achieve a working solution

I'd recommend using Promises - which are just glorified callbacks anyway, with the added advantage of being able to be used with `async`/`await` - this has the advantage of making the code *look* more like the code you're used to if you haven't done much asynchronous coding

```js
function statusmssgDialog() {
  const dlg = document.getElementById('cres_statusmssg');
  dlg.showModal();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const clk = function(e) {
      resolve(this.dataset.value === 'true');
      dlg.close();
    };
    dlg.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn =>
      btn.addEventListener('click', clk, { once: true})
    );
  });
}



// usage - it's easier if the function where you
//    call statusmssgDialog is `async`
//    but you can also use Promise.then/.catch of course
//
async function fn() {
  if( true /*changedStatus()*/){
    const mAns = await statusmssgDialog();
    console.log(`user action is ${mAns}`);
    if(!mAns) return mAns;
  }
  console.log('doing more things here when yes is clicked or chengedStatus is false?');
}



// asynchrony is like a virus, 
// anything that calls an asynchronous function and needs the result
// needs to be written to account for asynchrony
// here, I use .then/.catch instead of async/await
// because await isn't an option at the top-level of code
// unless it's the top-level of a module script in modern browsers 
fn().then(r => {
  if (r === false) {
    console.log('cancel was clicked');
    return;
  }
  console.log('yes was clicked');
});
```

```css
.modal-dialog {
  border-radius: 9px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em rgb(127 127 127 / 0.8);
  width: 30rem;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.modal-dialog::backdrop {
  background: rgb(0 0 0 / 0.4);
  backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
}
body {
  background-color: hsl(240 100% 95%);
}
```

```html
<dialog id="cres_statusmssg" class="modal-dialog">
  <div>
    <p>Changing your status will alter your estate plan and may cause you to lose some data. Do you want to proceed?</p>
    <button id="cres_yes" data-value="true">Yes</button>
    <button id="cres_cancel" data-value="false">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</dialog>

<div>
  <p>Dummy page text</p>
<div>
```

In the above, the dialog promise always resolves, but there is an alternative, to reject if cancel is pressed

```js
function statusmssgDialog() {
  const dlg = document.getElementById('cres_statusmssg');
  dlg.showModal();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const clk = function(e) {
      dlg.close();
      if (this.dataset.value !== 'true') {
        return reject('cancel pressed');
      }
      resolve('yes pressed');
    };
    dlg.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn =>
      btn.addEventListener('click', clk, { once: true})
    );
  });
}

async function fn() {
  if( true /*changedStatus()*/) {
    try {
      const mAns = await statusmssgDialog();
      console.log(`yes pressed`);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('cancel was pressed');
      throw e; // pass the cancel "error" to the caller
    }
  }
  console.log('doing more things here when yes is clicked or chengedStatus is false?');
}

fn().then(r => {
  console.log('yes was clicked');
}).catch(e => {
  console.log(`user action was ${e}`);
});
```

```css
.modal-dialog {
  border-radius: 9px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em rgb(127 127 127 / 0.8);
  width: 30rem;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.modal-dialog::backdrop {
  background: rgb(0 0 0 / 0.4);
  backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
}
body {
  background-color: hsl(240 100% 95%);
}
```

```html
<dialog id="cres_statusmssg" class="modal-dialog">
  <div>
    <p>Changing your status will alter your estate plan and may cause you to lose some data. Do you want to proceed?</p>
    <button id="cres_yes" data-value="true">Yes</button>
    <button id="cres_cancel" data-value="false">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</dialog>

<div>
  <p>Dummy page text</p>
<div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use Bootstrap Modal

[Using Twitter bootstrap modal instead of confirm dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218444/using-twitter-bootstrap-modal-instead-of-confirm-dialog)

Or jquery ui

[How to implement "confirmation" dialog in Jquery UI dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887029/how-to-implement-confirmation-dialog-in-jquery-ui-dialog)

Comment: How will this replace confirm?

Comment: Yes, I was confused, thanks, I edited my answer